# Indirect and increment rows?

Tags: excel, increment

I need to collect the values from a column for every 11th row, but I don't want to write out the cell reference in every cell because I have a lot of data that will be continually updated (E.g A3, A14, A25).  Is there a way I can use indirect and row+11 so this can auto update when I drag down? For example: Column A=Project, Column B=Project Name. I only need a list of the project names for every 11th row where column A says "Project". Appreicate any help!

Answer (score 0):

If the first cell is `A3` you can enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$3,(ROW(1:1)-1)*11,0)
```

anywhere, and drag down to get every 11th row value of column `A`